# Writing array to a file

Tags: php

In the program below

```
$array[name1][0] = 'name';
$array[name1][1] = '11';
$array[name2][0] = 'name2';
$array[name2][1] = '11';
$fileName = "file.php"
$fp = fopen($fileName,'w');
$msg = $array;
fwrite($fp,$msg);
fclose($fp);
```

In this file "file.php", i want to write an array...such tha its read like

```
<?
$array[name1][0] = 'name';
$array[name1][1] = '11';
$array[name2][0] = 'name2';
$array[name2][1] = '11';
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export) function does just that:

```
fprintf($fp, '<?php $array = %s;', var_export($array, true));
```

It generates valid PHP code and you can include the file after that:

```
include "file.php";
```

---

Note that you can `return` from a PHP file, so this would work too:

```
fprintf($fp, '<?php return %s;', var_export($array, true));
```

And then:

```
$array = include "file.php";
```

---

Alternatives to generating PHP code are [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode)/[`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode), or [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize)/[`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize).

Answer (score 2):

Use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) or [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to get a storable (and compact) representation of your data structure, then [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) or [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
fwrite($fp,print_r($msg,true));
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest you're going to get, natively, is by using [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) and writing its return value to the file.

Failing that, you should implement something to build that format from an Array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to read the file later and get an PHP array back, then you need to "serialize" the array:

and later

$array = unserialize(file_get_contents("test.data"));

if it should look readable in the file, you var_export($array,1) or print_r($array,1) and store their output.